# Merging Multiple CSV Files without merging the header

Tags: macos, command-line, csv

I need to merge multiple .CSV files (using the `cat` command) but without copying the header for each file.

What's the best way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 45):

You'll need more than the `cat` command, as described [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/a-little-bash-help-cat-multiple-files-together-except-first-line-788049/):

Say you have 3 CSV-files: `file1.csv`, `file2.csv`, and `file3.csv` and want to join them to `bigfile.csv` and your header is always (only) the first line, then use

either (keep header from first file "file1.csv"):

```
cat file1.csv <(tail +2 file2.csv) <(tail +2 file3.csv) > bigfile.csv
```

or (remove header from all files who's names begin with "file"):

```
awk 'FNR > 1' file*.csv > bigfile.csv
```

Comment: I found this looking for a generic linux answer, but in my case this didn't exactly work. It would silently ignore file1.csv. I needed to cat that file.  
  
`cat <(cat file1.csv) <(tail +2 file2.csv) <(tail +2 file3.csv) > bigfile.csv`

Comment: actually I had to use `tail -n+2`, `tail +2` wouldn't work

Answer (score 35):

I agree with the top answer but I suggest to extend it with the following scenario (as I can not comment):

If you want the output file to contain header (once) the correct script is:

`awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' file*.csv > bigfile.csv`

FNR represents the number of the processed record in a single file. And NR represents it globally, so first line is accepted and the rest are ignored as before.

Comment: I keep comming back to this answer everytime I come across a CSV file merge on command line, requiring to keep the header of only one file.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use a group command (`{ ; }`) instead of process substitution (`<()`):

```
{ head -n1 file1.csv; for f in file*.csv; do tail -n+2 "$f"; done; } > new.csv
```

It also works with CRLF line endings as long as the files end with an empty line (`\r\n`).

The number-only versions of head and tail were made obsolete by POSIX 1003.1-2001, and they result in warnings in some environments.

Answer (score 2):

Needed to concatenate two large CSVs with identical columns into larger CSV for chunking script (data does not have unique id's).

**First took header out of second csv**

```
awk 'FNR > 1' file2.csv > file2_noheading.csv
```

**Next, concatenated via the following**

```
cat file1.csv file2_noheading.csv > newfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the command sequence above resulted in a file looking like this:

```
header,of,csv1
contents,of,csv1
==> csv2.csv

contents,of,csv2
```

To make it a proper CSV, with one header line and all the relevant values, I employed the following `sed` incantation... `sed -ie "/^$/d;/^==>/d" bigfile.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Easier Solution if you have a ton of files :

```
awk 'FNR > 1' *.csv > merged.csv
```

Just go back to edit the big file and add the header back in.

Comment: How is your answer any different than what was all ready presented by iolsmit in 2013, being `awk 'FNR > 1' file*.csv > bigfile.csv`? It's not!

Comment: Re: how is it any different? It is a more terse answer and the one that I copied and pasted, at least : ) Gets my upvote

Comment: This is a good answer, because you don’t need all the files to start with `file`

Answer (score 1):

Give [***joinem***](https://github.com/mmore500/joinem) a try, available via PyPi: `python3 -m pip install joinem`.

*joinem* provides a CLI for fast, flexbile concatenation of tabular data using [polars](https://pola.rs).
I/O is *lazily streamed* in order to give good performance when **working with numerous, large files**.

### Example Usage

Pass input files via stdin and output file as an argument.

```bash
ls -1 path/to/*.csv | python3 -m joinem out.csv
```

You can add the `--progress` flag to get a progress bar.

### Further Information

*joinem* is also compatible with parquet, JSON, and feather file types.
See the project's [README](https://github.com/mmore500/joinem/) for more usage examples and a full command-line interface API listing.

*disclosure*: I am the library author of *joinem*.